# Django nginx looking at static not staticfiles

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, nginx-config

I can't work this out, nginx insists on looking in a "static" folder even though I think I have given "staticfiles" as the location. Yet the logs are constantly showing the work "static" in the file path. Here is the nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10.88.58.95;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    root /srv/pcc_django/;
    location /staticfiles/ {
    }

location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

...

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

...

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

This is what the access logs are showing:

```
10.184.52.12 - - [18/Oct/2019:12:58:58 +0000] "GET /static/css/microblog/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 77 "http://10.88.58.95/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0" "-"
10.184.52.12 - - [18/Oct/2019:12:58:58 +0000] "GET /static/images/microblog/platform_control.png HTTP/1.1" 404 77 "http://10.88.58.95/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0" "-"
10.184.52.12 - - [18/Oct/2019:13:03:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5916 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0" "-"
10.184.52.12 - - [18/Oct/2019:13:03:58 +0000] "GET /static/css/microblog/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 77 "http://10.88.58.95/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0" "-"
10.184.52.12 - - [18/Oct/2019:13:03:58 +0000] "GET /static/images/microblog/platform_control.png HTTP/1.1" 404 77 "http://10.88.58.95/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0" "-"
10.184.52.12 - - [18/Oct/2019:13:03:58 +0000] "GET /static/css/microblog/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 77 "http://10.88.58.95/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0" "-"
10.184.52.12 - - [18/Oct/2019:13:03:58 +0000] "GET /static/images/microblog/platform_control.png HTTP/1.1" 404 77 "http://10.88.58.95/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0" "-"
10.184.52.12 - - [18/Oct/2019:13:05:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5916 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0" "-"
10.184.52.12 - - [18/Oct/2019:13:05:58 +0000] "GET /static/css/microblog/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 77 "http://10.88.58.95/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0" "-"
10.184.52.12 - - [18/Oct/2019:13:05:58 +0000] "GET /static/images/microblog/platform_control.png HTTP/1.1" 404 77 "http://10.88.58.95/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0" "-"
```

How do I get nginx to look at the correct folder please, it should be looking at:

```
/srv/pcc_django/staticfiles/
```

it's currently looking at:

```
/srv/pcc_django/static/
```

which is in the same folder. If I swap the names over it works, so I'm certain that my settings.ph file is correctly configured regarding DEBUG = False which is the current setting on the server.

UPDATE: I have just edited the nginx.conf file to the following:

```
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /staticfiles {
    root /srv/pcc_django;
    }
```

and got this from the error log:

```
2019/10/21 13:22:00 [error] 5888#0: *1 open() "/srv/pcc_django/staticfiles/static/admin/css/responsive.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.184.53.51, server: 10.88.58.95, request: "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1", host: "10.88.58.95", referrer: "http://10.88.58.95/admin/"
```

I don't understand where the /static/ is coming from, nginx, or django, what can I do to verify where the problem actually is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django settings was set up correctly, the issue is with nginx.conf adding an alias of the absolute path to my css fixed my issue.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10.88.58.95;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static {
             alias /srv/pcc_django/staticfiles/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Django looks in the static folder provided in setting `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL`. The first should be "/staticfiles/". The second should match a `location` in your nginx to map to a server directory.

```
location /static {
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    alias /some/path/in/your/server/;
}
```

Comment: I'm still very confused and the above still does not work, I've added the relevant parts from my settings.py file. The staticfiles folder and a static folder are in the same directory, so surely I have to write the words "staticfiles" somewhere in the nginx.conf file, but changing static to staticfiles in nginx removes all the css not just the admin css.

Comment: If you wanna /staticfiles/, your location should match it. If you're in production, please run `python manage.py collectstatic` so Django can move all staticfiles to this folder nginx can serve.

Comment: Check this: nginx's `location /staticfiles/` == Django's `STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'` and the location alias folder == `STATIC_ROOT`